# How can I extract credit card substring from a string using python

Tags: python, credit-card

I am new to python and I hope someone can help me with this. I need to extract credit card numbers from a string. e.g

"My credit card number is 1234-2312-2312-2312" or
"My Credict card number is 1234 1234 1832 1234"

Anyone knows how I can do it?

Comment: use regex to find numbers from a string.

Comment: Hi Harsh, thanks for the reply. Is there any way I could get CC numbers with spaces similar to this 1234 1234 1832 1234 through regex?

Comment: For that you need to check what is string after space. If there is number go ahead else stop

Comment: How robust does this need to be?  What if they use slashes between the numbers?  Or periods?  What if the four numbers are on separate lines?

Comment: A very simple regex would be `[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{4}`, meaning "four digits, followed by any single character, followed by four digits, followed by any single character, followed by four digits, followed by any single character, followed by four digits."

Comment: Hi John, thank you for this. The possible format would only be with - between numbers or space between numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this using regex

```
import re

def findCardNumber(string):
    pattern = r"(^|\s+)(\d{4}[ -]\d{4}[ -]\d{4}[ -]\d{4})(?:\s+|$)"

    match = re.search(pattern, string)

    if match:
        print(match.group(0))

findCardNumber("My Credict card number is 1234 1234 1832 1234")
```

This also considers the location of your card number in the string, it can be anywhere - at the beginning, somewhere in the middle or at the end.

Comment: this is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Akbar, I have one last question. How would I extract the cc number from match.group(0)? For example I have 2 CC numbers. How would I get each and store in a variable for example?

Comment: Hi! If you have more than one CC numbers in one string, then the "match" variable will include all of them. You extract each using "group" method specifying which one you want to extract. So the first CC number is stored in "match.group(0)", while the second one is in "match.group(1)", and so on.

Comment: Yup I got it! But I noticed something. When the pattern is like this

My credit card number is: 1234 1234 1234 1234

the result also includes the ":" character. Any idea why?

e.g ": 1234 1234 1234 1234"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, my bad, instead of \W it should be \s in regex pattern string, meaning any white space characters. I edited the answer too.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Hi Kamar! I have a question again. How can i get CC number with "." at the end? e.g "1234-4567-2345-2345." Hopy you can help me again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just add dot into your regex like this: (^|\s+)(\d{4}[ -]\d{4}[ -]\d{4}[ -]\d{4}.)(?:\s+|$)